# Get current playing song from spotify

Tags: android

Trying to make an app that get current playing song and output it. Tried a IntentFilter for the stock music player and that works great. But this wont work on Spotify, so my question is if there is any way to get the song information from the spotify app?

Comment: There is an ARM based C-library that you can load on the Android platform.  See here for download info: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/

Answer (score 0):

I think they have an SDK for this:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-media-notifications/

Not sure if it's still being maintained and if it works. Also not sure if possible to get the album art.