# How does the android lockscreen get playing song?

Tags: android

Recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199293/get-current-playing-song-from-spotify) how to get the current song playing from the music app spotify, there seems by the response that there are no easy way of doing this.

The android lockscreen at least in 4.0+ will show the current song and works with almost any music player including spotify. So my question is how does the lockscreen get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), you can create a broadcast receiver and define filters for it in the manifest. Then all the music applications that send this broadcast will trigger your  onReceive method, along with the information sent from the app.

> EDIT:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
    intent.putExtra("playing", (mState & FLAG_PLAYING) != 0);
    if (song != null) {
        intent.putExtra("track", song.title);
        intent.putExtra("album", song.album);
        intent.putExtra("artist", song.artist);
        intent.putExtra("songid", song.id);
        intent.putExtra("albumid", song.albumId);
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This is the code in the stock player used to send broadcast, Look into  broadcast receiver and you able be able to figure out how to get the data needed.

Also You will need to find the filter for spotify, AFIK This one works for soptify.
"com.android.music.metachanged" or look here http://pastebin.com/ukfPnZwg

Comment: Do you have an example? were can i find this in the lockscreen source code?

Comment: I have added the code you need the extract the data from the intent.

Comment: Also added another link with a test app which does this. 
Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: As you say this is sent by the stock player, my problem is that im not trying to get this information from the stock player but a player called spotify. This method you described doesn't work on it, but it has to be some other way due to that the lockscreen can show it.

Comment: Use this app to figure out all the broadcasts for spotify 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.broadcastlogger
and the build a receiver for that broadcast.

Comment: The app you linked seems to only be for "Internal Broadcasts" and not include the intents from the music players. Is there any other way to get hold of the intent?

Answer (score 5):

On Android 4.0 and 4.1, the portion of the lockscreen you are seeing is called the "remote controls". You can [call `registerRemoteControlClient()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerRemoteControlClient%28android.media.RemoteControlClient%29) to supply information to it.

On Android 4.2+, you are welcome to create your own lockscreen-capable app widget instead.

Comment: This should be accepted answer since this is how the lockscreen get the currently playing song.